# How to run a web process without opening web browser in VB6

Tags: vba, web-services, web, vb6

i want to run a web process without opening web browser. I want to update the entry but when i click the button i dont want to open a web page. i did in c# but i need to do it in vb6.0

Example:

on button click

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://example.com/_change_status.php? id=67&new_status=2")
WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(myUri)
WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Comment: You can use XMLHTTP for this.  Having a GET request perform an update is not considered a good practice though...

Answer (score 2):

Set a reference to `Microsoft XML 6.0` , then :

```
Sub webQuery()

    Dim strURL                  As String
    Dim strResponse             As String
    Dim XMLHttpRequest          As xmlhttp

    strURL = "http://example.com/_change_status.php? id=67&new_status=2"

    Set XMLHttpRequest = New MSXML2.xmlhttp
    XMLHttpRequest.Open "GET", strURL, False
    XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHttpRequest.send

    strResponse = XMLHttpRequest.responsetext
    Set XMLHttpRequest = Nothing

End Sub
```